# ASP.MVC return image doesn't work in BBCODE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-mvc-routing, bbcode

i have some simple code

```
public virtual ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ImagesEntities())
    {
        var b = db.Images.SingleOrDefault(bo => bo.Id == id);
        return File("C:\\images\\" + b.FileName, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

It works in html for example
< img src="http://mysite.com/mycontroler/Get/1" />

but on some forums with BBCode it doesnt work
and returns plain text instead of image

any help?

Comment: What's the test it's returning? It's possible that it's throwing an exception...

Comment: Try returning `FileResult` and see what happens. Also yes, what is it returning and is it throwing an exception? Also, is the IIS process running under an account that has rights to read from c:\images? Also, try escaping your file path like `@"C:\images\"` instead of escaping individual back slashes, that way you can see better when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Url must ends with '.jpg', '.png' etc....